# When Scraping got html with "encoded" part, is it possible to get it

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

One of the final steps in my project is to get the price of a product , i got everything i need except the price.

Source :

```
<div class="prices">
<div class="price">
    <div class="P01 tooltip"><span>Product 1</span></div>€<div class="encoded" data-price="bzMzlXaZjkxLjUxNA==">151.4</div>
</div>
<div class="price">
    <div class="Po1plus tooltip"><span>Product 1 +</span></div>€<div class="encoded" data-price="MGMSKJDFsTcxLjU0NA==">184.4</div>
</div>
```

what i need to get is after the

> ==">

I don't know if there is some protection from the encoded part, but the clostest i get is returnig this `<div class="encoded" data-price="bzMzlXaZjkxLjUxNA=="></div>`

Don't know if is relevant i'm using "html.parser" for the parsing

PS. i'm not trying to hack anything, this is just a personal project to help me learn.

Edit: if when parsing the test i get no price, the other methods can get it without a different parser ?

EDIT2 :
this is my code :

```
page_soup = soup(pagehtml, "html.parser")
pricebox = page_soup.findAll("div",{ "id":"stationList"})
links = pricebox[0].findAll("a",)
det = links[0].findAll("div",)

det[7].text
#or 
det[7].get_text()
```

the result is ''

Comment: You got a div tag of class encloded. *"what i need to get is [the price] after the `==">`"* That's called the tag **content**. You want to extract the tag content.

Comment: @smci Yes......

Comment: The source code posted above, did you get it from your browser or within `python`? To finish that thought: are you sure the content is not `JavaScript`-generated?

Comment: well i really don't know about JavaScript, didn't see anything in source code, but i just tryed it with lxml and got this : <Element p at 0x270deaf9f48>

Comment: @LcrossPortugal What I meant was where did you copy the above source code from? From your internet browser or from python? Also, it would help if you posted an update of how you tried using `lxml`. (`<Element p at 0x270deaf9f48>` might mean you need to use the `text_content` method to extract the text)

Answer (score 2):

### With Regex

I suppose there are ways to do this using `beautifulsoup`, anyway here is one approach using `regex`

```
import regex

# Assume 'source_code' is the source code posted in the question
prices = regex.findall(r'(?<=data\-price[\=\"\w]+\>)[\d\.]+(?=\<\/div)', source_code)
# ['151.4', '184.4']
# or
[float(p) for p in prices]
# [151.4, 184.4]
```

Here is a short explanation of the regular expression:

- `[\d\.]+` is what we are actually searching: `\d` means digits, `\.` denotes the period and the two combined in the square brackets with the `+` means we want to find at least one digit/period
- The brackets before/after further specify what has to precede/succeed a potential match
- `(?<=data\-price[\=\"\w]+\>)` means before any potential match there must be `data-price...>` where `...` is at least one of the symbols `A-z0-9="`
- Finally, `(?=\<\/div)` means after any match must be followed by `</div`

---

### With lxml

Here is an approach using the module `lxml`

```
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(source_code)
[float(p.text_content()) for p in tree.find_class('encoded')]
# [151.4, 184.4]
```

Comment: sir, Actually he's is able to get `<div class="encoded" data-price="bzMzlXaZjkxLjUxNA=="></div>` this part of the HTML only he want's the prices for now. And in your answer, you are telling all the possible ways.

Comment: @0xPrateek I do not really understand your comment: OP wants to scrap the prices from the source code, I indicated some possible solutions.

Comment: When you see the question again you will find he was asking for two things, 1- > `what i need to get is after the
==">` and, 2-) `Don't know if is relevant i'm using "html.parser" for the parsing`

Comment: @0xPrateek Precisely and if you follow that thought and look in the source code you will see that what follows is `['151.4', '184.4']` which is what I provided in both solutions. So again, what exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: I was saying that question was asking for something else and you tried to provide a solution in your own way. As he was able to get `<div class="encoded" data-price="bzMzlXaZjkxLjUxNA=="></div>` this and he only need the tag content.

Comment: @0xPrateek Look, as far as I'm concerned I believe your answer should be accepted since you not only delivered the expected output but also followed OP's initial idea using `html.parser`. That being said, I didn't `try to provide a solution`, I *provided a solution* by yielding *what was asked*.

Comment: i'm sorry if i didn't asked the question in the best way, i'll try to clear things up. The part i could get on my own returned everything but the price , that's why i mensioned the parser, because i get no text even with the tag.get_text()

Answer (score 1):

`"html.parser"` works fine as a parser for your problem. As you are able to get this `<div class="encoded" data-price="bzMzlXaZjkxLjUxNA=="></div>` on your own that means you only need prices now and for that you can use `get_text()` which is an inbuilt function present in BeautifulSoup.

This function returns whatever the text is in between the tags.

**Syntax of get_text()** :`tag_name.get_text()`

Solution to your problem :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data ='''
<div class="prices">
<div class="price">
    <div class="P01 tooltip"><span>Product 1</span></div>€<div class="encoded" data-price="bzMzlXaZjkxLjUxNA==">151.4</div>
</div>
<div class="price">
    <div class="Po1plus tooltip"><span>Product 1 +</span></div>€<div class="encoded" data-price="MGMSKJDFsTcxLjU0NA==">184.4</div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

# Searching for all the div tags with class:encoded
a = soup.findAll ('div', {'class' : 'encoded'})

# Using list comprehension to get the price out of the tags
prices = [price.get_text() for price in a]
print(prices)
```

**Output**

```
['151.4', '184.4']
```

Hope you get what you are looking for. :)

Comment: i was hoping your answer would resolve this, but it didn't...if i didn't mess things up i ended up with taginquestion.get_text()--- ' '. returned empty just like it did previously.

Comment: @LcrossPortugal Make sure you are not using `get_text()` on a list variable. It would be helpful if you Can share the code how you are fetching the tags.